# How to make smarty output error info?

Tags: php, smarty

Seems by default smarty eats up all errors(even nothing in php's log):

```
{$value|nosuchapi}
```

How to make it output error info when it calls an function that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can say, smarty accepts any function after the pipe and does not throw errors.

PHP however will generate an error, if the function `nosuchapi` exists and returns an error. This behaviour can be controlled by your php.ini file with `error_reporting` and `display_errors`.

The first one, I'm afraid, can not be modified.